# Can I expose multiple webHttpBinding endpoints in the same port in Biztalk?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, webhttpbinding

I would like to have two endpoints with the same port and the same name, but hosted on different tcp port with different transport security settings.
I.e https://endpoint:443/ and http://endpoint:80

I know I  need to change endpoint name because of error

```
Address should be unique for Receive Location 'xxxx'.
Address 'endpointlink.svc' is already present for Receive Location
```

Is there any trick that let me use the same endpoints name?

Comment: Port or Receive Location?   And I take it you are talking URL rather than name

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051134/can-wcf-tcp-and-http-endpoints-have-the-same-port

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I added example to the question. I need 2 RL with the same biztalk port. Endpoints need to be exposed on different tcp ports i.e 443 and 80

Comment: @TheobaldDu I think this is something different that my example. I need to use different tcp ports

Comment: On different ports, the encryption protocol you use is also different. As far as I know, this is impossible. Here is the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051134/can-wcf-tcp-and-http-endpoints-have-the-same-port